# k ubuntu - finding out command execution source (cron?)

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu

I got an kubuntu desktop box. This box is neatly set up and suits all my needs.

However: the previous owner had the box shutdown at 23:30 (11pm 30 Mins) every day in order to save electric power.

Syslog tells me:

> 23:30:02 kubuntu-871263 CRON[17372]: (root) CMD (^I/sbin/poweroff)

I therefore investigated

`crontab -l`

`17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 22   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 22   * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 22   1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )`

for root and all users.

I can't find the origin of the poweroff command. Any ideas where the command at 23:30 is originating from.

PS I can't ask the previous owner.

Comment: Do you see any data in `/etc/cron.d/daily` etc?

Comment: Good idea --- there was nothing. BUT I found a crontab file in /etc that is the systemwide crontab. This file contained the poweroff command at 23:30. THANKs for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a crontab file in /etc that is the systemwide crontab (/etc/crontab) . This file contained the poweroff command at 23:30.